# How to stop sound using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a sound file in my html file. I would like to stop playing it after 30 seconds using javascript, below is the code to play

```
var snd = new Audio("sound location");
snd.play();
```

Any help?

Comment: take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout and use the snd.pause functionality

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    snd.pause();
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Or simply just `setTimeout(snd.pause, 30000)` ?

Comment: No, @Derek朕會功夫 that will **not** work. And I think is answer is simple enough.

Comment: @Pinocchio - Why not?

Comment: Because in the pause function it would refer to snd as this and if you do it like that the this will be changed by the timeout to window

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 Audio Element has a few methods that you should know about.

```
audioElement.pause(); // Will pause the audio

audioElement.play(); // Will play the audio

audioElement.volume = 0.5; // Will set the volume to half of max

audioElement.load(); // Will start to load the media

audioElement.currentTime = 0; // Will set the time of the audio to 0
```

And if you wan't to stop the audio there you can do something like this.

```
audioElement.pause();
audioElement.currentTime = 0;
```

So to answer your question you can use `setTimeout` and the **stop** way

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
   audioElement.pause();
   audioElement.currentTime = 0;
}, 30 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setTimeout(snd.pause.bind(snd), 30000);
```

Comment: `snd.pause` would be called with `window` as `this` if passed this way.  Maybe `snd.pause.bind(snd) would work`.